# Black diamonds and questions marks in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Keep having a nightmare with weird characters appearing when I move a wordpress site from local to live server. Black diamonds and questions marks dotted around all over the place.

http://dev16.lorifitzgerald.co.uk/

Ive googled this hard and none of the answers, most of which seem to be very old, don't seem to work. They all relate to changing the character encoding.

Really stuck with this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pound-sign-causing-content-curtailment and verified your own php settings?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a text encoding issue. Check that all your files are utf-8 and unix style returns.

Sometimes if you edit a theme or file locally you can accidentally change or override the text encoding.

Comment: Thanks. The encoding is already UTF-8. Im stuggling to understand what you mean by 'unix style returns though'...?

Comment: LF vs CR for line breaks - that's how unix-like file systems format their text files.